# Obtaining subclasses in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Single Table Inheritance using the following structure:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Restaurant < Business
end

class Bar < Business
end
```

and wanted to get a list of subclasses as a string array, so for Business -> ['Restaurant', 'Bar']

Any ideas on how I would go about this?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to handle it.

**Opinion** I personally like this approach because the parent can define specific behavior or configuration when a child class is inheriting from the parent

```
class Business

  @@children = []

  def self.inherited(klass)
    @@children << klass
  end

  def self.children
    @@children
  end

end

class Restaurant < Business; end
class Bar < Business; end
```

Let's see it work

```
Business.children
#=> [Restaurant, Bar]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
Business.descendants.map {|klass| klass.name.demodulize } #generally I nest descendant in the main class namespace, hence the demodulize
```

Btw, due to Rails dev environment principles, you could have issues when developing.

Example, if you use a scope: `Business.a_scope` you could encounter issues.

It's known and the known way to proceed id to add at the bottom of your main class (`Business` here) something like:

```
your_children_types.each do |type|
  require_dependency "#{Rails.root}/app/models/#{ path_to_your_child(type) }"
end
```

Comment: Note: This is a Rails convenience method. Don't try it in vanilla Ruby, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the reputation to comment on @naomik's answer, but if you're using Rails please remember to also add 'super' after your additions to the inherited method, like:

```
def self.inherited(klass)
  @@children << klass
  super # this is 'super' important to not wipe out Rails' descendant tracker
end
```